# Xamarin iOS Firebase Cloud Messaging - Push Notifications - can not send test message with device token

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

Xamarin iOS Firebase Cloud Messaging - Push Notifications. I am sending notification from: 
I can send notification for android device ("send test message" from https://console.firebase.google.com)   and it works. 
Android device token looks like:

```
dffplp_ekKY:APA91bEVk83i3ZAA-ZB7FQZ4nlwCCxhkMdEQIH4nOiuHI7nI50VZs4Ti4Gsm-gHxtwfb6OvkQSXNI0kls71Fch2bGT6nN3lIzmZ1x1uzizlTKO9PaEibUG02CR-dGVdu6vclid4l3aDY
```

on iOS in AppDelegate.cs:

```
  public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
   {
        var thisToken = deviceToken.Description;
        var DeviceToken = Regex.Replace(deviceToken.ToString(), "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");
   }
```

thisToken is:

```
<e24cad44 37d26c68 6c3defad f3685749 70c0180e 56526ae4 8ceb9253 e280d7a9>
```

DeviceToken is:

```
e24cad4437d26c686c3defadf368574970c0180e56526ae48ceb9253e280d7a9
```

Now I go to https://console.firebase.google.com and try to send test message via device token, but nothing appears on real device. When I send notification via Target -> bundleId  then it works perfectly on iOS.

I read this:
https://medium.com/@kevinle/correctly-capture-ios-13-device-token-in-xamarin-3d0fa390b71b but actually I am compiling against iOS SDK 12.1 and the real device is iOS 13.3 so new changes (weird device token) does not affect my code.

The question is: does console.firebase.google.com function "send test message" has problem when I try to send notification using formatted (only letters and numbers) device token on iOS (android is working good) or the token that I have is wrong formatted or invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should register token with this method

```
[Export("messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:")]
public void DidReceiveRegistrationToken(Messaging messaging, string fcmToken)
{
    // Monitor token generation: To be notified whenever the token is updated.
    Console.WriteLine("Received token: " + fcmToken);
    // Handle here how your app is storing token locally or send it to server
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}
```

Comment: I am receiving fcmToken from DidReceiveRegistrationToken method - long strong. What is actually the difference between this token compare to token from RegisteredForRemoteNotifications method? I have two dirrerent tokens in the same app. Finally none of them can be used to send notification with success.

Comment: To my knowledge this is proper method to receive token with latest firebase update. With this method I have no problems with sending firebase ios notifications to specific device.

Comment: Ok, your solution gave me long string as fcmToken. Using this token at beginning my real device didn't receive any notifications, but today (after couple of days), iphone is receiving notifications. The question is: does Apple notification system needs time to get working with new registered apps? Delay of several days?

Comment: Most unlikely. My apps are receiving tokens immediately. My guess is that you were updating your app. New tokens are received when app is installed on the device, so basically you must uninstall your app completely and reinstall to receive new token. That is why it is nice to implement function that can recreate token on demand.